# Literally copied a section from my other page and it doesn't look good?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, frontend

I've been making this website and I use one stylesheet for all html pages.
I've made this little section on one page, and I wanted to include it in my other page as well. I literally copied the same html (and the css is the same because it uses the same file) and it looks different. Anyone have an Idea on this?

[image: What it looks like on 1st page]

[image: What it looks like on 2nd page]

```css
.main-section {
  position: relative;
}

.main-img-div {
  /* background-image: url("img/pexels-nerfee-mirandilla-3186654.jpg");
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size:cover;
        filter: blur(8px);
        -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
        height: 300px;
        width: 100%;
        margin: -5px -10px -10px -5px;
        overflow: hidden;
        */
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-img {
  object-fit: contain;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: brightness(50%) blur(1px);
}

.main-img-content {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  /*top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.main-button {
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 4px solid white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition: ease-in 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
}

.main-button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  text-shadow: none;
}

.main-img-text {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-section">
  <div class="main-img-div">
    <img src="style/img/pexels-nerfee-mirandilla-3186654.jpg" class="main-img" alt="Image of the food we're offering">
  </div>
  <div class="main-img-content">
    <p class="main-img-text">
      Ever wanted to enjoy cuisine from all parts of the world, all in one place? You're at the right address! Click the button to see more details on our food.
    </p>
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="main-button">Enter The Kitchen</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add your `html` and create snippet so we can check..

Comment: .main-img-content does not have a width. Only reason why it worked was because you have huge text that made it take up the page width

Comment: Could you show both pages HYML?

Answer (score 0):

There is no width on the content so it just sits on the right like you told it to do.

```css
.main-section {
  position: relative;
}

.main-img-div {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  align-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main-img {
  object-fit: contain;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
  -moz-filter: blur(5px);
  -o-filter: blur(5px);
  -ms-filter: blur(5px);
  filter: brightness(50%) blur(1px);
}

.main-img-content {
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgb(0, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  /*top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.main-button {
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 4px solid white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  transition: ease-in 0.3s;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 10px;
}

.main-button:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  text-shadow: none;
}

.main-img-text {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-shadow: 0px 2px 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.57);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-section">
  <div class="main-img-div">
    <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300" class="main-img" alt="Image of the food we're offering">
  </div>
  <div class="main-img-content">
    <p class="main-img-text">
      X
    </p>
    <br>
    <a href="#" class="main-button">X</a>
  </div>
</div>
```